My visual Studio code keeps quiting automatically whenever I open it
My visual Studio code keeps quiting automatically whenever I open it .
i also try to delete vscode and clear system and user cache after the fresh installation it works but
when i login my github user and sync my setting and extension and restart my vscode its again quiting automatically.
OS: MacOs Big Sure
when i try to open vscode from vscode.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron its through.
Error :
[0710/154745.920097:ERROR:crash_report_database_mac.mm(753)] open lock /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Code/Crashpad/pending/9cc4b32c-16db-4912-856c-8eba48913b0d.dmp: Resource temporarily unavailable (35)
[1650:0710/154746.310512:ERROR:node_bindings.cc(162)] Fatal error in V8: v8::Template::Set Invalid value, must be a primitive or a Template
[0710/154746.318007:WARNING:process_memory_mac.cc(94)] mach_vm_read(0x7ffedfd95000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[0710/154746.539927:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)] UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5)
[0710/154746.540019:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(43)] opendir /Users/[username]/Library/Application Support/Code/Crashpad/attachments/f2fcfb19-0b0d-4048-9c0e-39553ed94fbb: No such file or directory (2)
Expected:
opens vs code without any issue .

I've had the same issue. Fixed with rollback to the version 1.87.2

thanks for you reply. reproduce the issue after installation of new vscode i try to add my extensions step by step to check the issue and i found that the Eslint extension is quitting vs code after i restart vscode for eslint .
could you help me out of this ? i wanna use this extension .
